# Unable to complete windows 7 install

Tags: windows-7

Here is my setup:

- ASUS ROG Crosshair VIII Dark Hero (Wi-Fi)
- 2 x 8GB Corsair Vengeance RGB
- AMD Ryzen 5600
- NZXT Kraken Z53
- Western Digital SN850 500GB
- Corsair RMx 650W 80+ Gold
- Rosewill USB hub & Card reader
- Logitech MK120 (mouse & keyboard)

I’ve tried about three different “bootable USB makers” and my best result is with the Gigabyte one; I can get through the install process, but when it reboots I get to this screen

[image: this screen]

with no way to progress: Can’t hit enter, can’t move the mouse. I’ve tried booting in safe mode, and it loads a list of what looks like driver files, then tells me “setup cannot be completed in safe mode” (Same result with new mouse & keyboard)

I’d prefer to be able to run Windows 7 on it rather than any other OS.

Is it possible to install W7 on this PC?

Comment: I don't think Windows 7 supports USB3 or NVMe out of the box, and essentially the USB disk boot is handled by your system firmware which then hands over USB to the OS installer which has no idea how to find your mouse and keyboard. I know it sucks but you might have to bite the bullet and use an OS that is supported on your system. Sorry, but this is the way technology goes sometimes, old software does not always run on newer hardware.

Comment: From https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-crosshair/rog-crosshair-viii-dark-hero-model/helpdesk_download it looks like the only supported systems are Win10 and Win 11, there may well be a lot of missing drivers for any older OS.

Comment: Regardless of the above, you may want to consider installing Windows 10 or 11. Win7 mainstream support ended in 2015, extended support over two years ago. That leaves you with a potentially vulnerable OS that will never be updated.

Comment: I think you are out of luck trying to install a dead operating system on a new machine. Use Windows 10 or 11 and if need be, Windows 7 in a virtual machine (that works).

Comment: Have you tried using the two USB 2.0 connectors for the keyboard and mouse? There is a chance that they are not routed via some subsystem that needs USB 3.0 drivers.

Comment: I had seen that suggestion somewhere, but I don’t think my system has USB 2.0. I’ve probably tried sticking the USB for the mouse & keyboard in every hole that puppy has though.

Comment: @Starrkya I think that the USB port labelled "BIOS" on the back could be USB 2.0. Although there are USB 2.0 headers on the motherboard, if you happen to have the right connectors with USB 2.0 sockets on the end of them. (E.g. I've used them on a different model of M/b to go to a 4-way USB 2.0 PCI card slot thing for mouse, keyboard, and other items that work fine at that speed.)

Comment: I wouldn’t want to mess with that BIOS one, because I don’t want to accidentally mess something up, but I think I have tried what you’re referring to. I don’t know why I didn’t put this in the list, but I’ve got a Rosewill USB hub/card reader plugged in, and I have tried using those USB ports